# Can monsters naturally spawn on blocks covered by pressure plate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a mob farm that uses mobs naturally spawned. I was wondering if a normal monster can spawn directly on pressure plate. This would allow me to crush them right after they appear.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but I just realised that I have just answered all 3 of your previous questions one after another in succession... you gotta give me credit for that man... JKJK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a short, simple **YES**. According to the [Minecraft WIKI](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Mob_spawning)

> While **individual mobs can spawn inside signs, pressure plates, and
> other non-opaque blocks**, packs cannot. They need a completely empty
> block in the center. Since a pack spawns all at one level, there needs
> to be some air blocks right above a flat surface to allow mobs to
> spawn on it, and more air blocks will always allow more spawning.

To give you an example of a mob pack, this is it:

[image]

> Example of a mob pack spawning. The 41×1×41 spawning area is shaded
> blue (not to scale). The yellow figures represent the actual positions
> that mobs could spawn in after checking the environment. Note that the
> mobs can spawn inside torch and ladder blocks. But they can't spawn on
> top of glass because it's not opaque. The red cube is the center of
> the pack, which must be an air block, but the blocks above and below
> it can be anything.

Comment: Note that having mobs spawn on pressure plates is often used to directly funnel then downwards to a collection area when water is no option, like in an "Ender ender".