# Do mobs no longer spawn on pressure plates in 1.10.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a large spawning area in the nether, where the only spawnable surfaces within a couple hundred blocks for mobs are on top of stone pressure plates.  (See screen shot below.)

I haven't played in over a year, and my spawning area in the nether has NO mobs spawning in it at all.  (See attached number of entities, the entities present are all minecarts, or chickens or players, no mobs.)  My render distance is set to 35, difficulty is set to hard.
[image]

This [question and answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183299/can-monsters-naturally-spawn-on-blocks-covered-by-pressure-plate) seem to imply otherwise, but I can think of no other explanation for the paucity of mobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, mobs cannot spawn on pressure plates anymore. This was a change in 1.9 release.

Mobs *can* spawn in tripwire, which might be a viable way to rebuild your farm.

Answer (score 0):

In 1.11, use string in place of the pressure plates and observers in place of the repeaters.

I'm not sure what to do in 1.10.2 though.